# Finding the formula for the summation $\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1) = 1+3+5+...+(2n-1)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm going through Calculus by Spivak and one of the questions is to find a formula for a summation.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1) = 1+3+5+...+(2n-1).$$

I got the correct answer, $n^2$, but did it an alternative method to the answer in the book and wanted some clarity on the working out.

Answer in the book:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1) &= 1+3+5+...+(2n-1) \\
&=1+2+3+...+2n-2(1+...+n)\\
&= \frac{(2n)(2n+1)}{2} -n(n+1)\\
&=n^2.
\end{align}$$

Why was this approach chosen, from the first to the second line, to me it was not obvious to go down the route of 'adding' in the missing terms, and then subtracting them at the end. Is this a common approach?

I just worked out the two summations, $\sum_{i=1}^n (2i)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n 1$ added them together and simplified the answer.

Comment: I don't know if there's any obvious reason.  You'd have to ask the solution writer.

Comment: "Is this a common approach?": all tricks are allowed !

Comment: This solution doesn't appear in the solution manual of the book.

Comment: Yes, it is the obvious approach, for problems of this nature.  An alternative approach is to recognize that $~1 + 3 = 2^2, ~1 + 3 + 5 = 3^2,~$ and then form a hypothesis, and then prove it by induction, using the fact that $~(k+1)^2 - k^2 = 2k+1.$

Answer (score 1):

The method they use is pretty common in calculating sums. Your method is the more obvious one and what I would have used in this question. However, at times the book's method is superior. For example, I can't find a way of calculating $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$$using your method. Using their method, we would rewrite this sum as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(2k)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}-\frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac34\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac34\times\frac{\pi^2}6=\frac{\pi^2}8$$I think the textbook's authors didn't use the method you used to prepare you for more difficult sums in the future. I don't have any other idea why they would use it in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think they do it in books because primitive techniques (tricks) are simple and common.

Here is the trick:

$\small\begin{array}{c}
S=&1&+&3&+&...&+&(2n-3)&+&(2n-1)\\
S=&(2n-1)&+&(2n-3)&+&...&+&3&+&1\\
2S=&2n&+&2n&+&...&+&2n&+&2n&\text{(n times)}\\
2S=&n(2n)\\
S=&n^2
\end{array}$

This idea is too old. We learned it from our teachers. You may see [A. Nesin's](https://youtube.com/shorts/w9GGyE5O7is?feature=share) nice illustration of this idea in youtube shorts.

Answer (score -1):

we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n2i-1=2\sum_{i=1}^n i-\sum_{i=1}^1=2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-n=...$$
for your second Problem write
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(4i^2-4i+1)=4\sum_{i=1}^ni^2-4\sum_{i=1}^ni+\sum_{i=1}^n1$$
can you finish this?
HINT: $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$

Comment: That is the way I did it. Just wondering why the way noted in the book was taken, as it was not immediately obvious to me to consider the approach.

Comment: ok the result is $n^2$, is the Problem solved now?

Comment: Umm, I guess, the second part is finding the formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = 1^2+3^2+5^2+...+(2n-1)^2.$ Would there it be possible to take the approach in the question I submitted, rather than the way you have noted?

Comment: have you solved it after my hint above?

Comment: Yeah, thank, but not the second one...

Comment: There is no second problem in the question. I looked to see if it had been edited away but there is no evidence in the current edit history.